# is google page speed wrong?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I have "just" got a new client with an existing magento webshop (www.roonrahn.com), which has a lot of issues. When I run a test on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=roonrahn.com&tab=desktop

the site scores poorly, which is no wonder; BUT when I download the "optimized" images, they are tiny! Not just in kb but in pixel size.

Why is google serving me these tiny images?

Maybe there is something wrong with the template, that google interpret weird?

Answer (score 1):

You can compress images using https://compressor.io/compress website.

Please optimize your website using below steps.

Go to website control panel
Click `System > Configuration > Developer`.
Here you can merge css and js.

**Note: Please merge css first and then check whole website in frontend and backend and then merge js and again check whole website.**

Then use https://www.apptrian.com/minify-html-css-js-for-magento extension to minify css and js, And then check speed at google.

Comment: http://www.roonrahn.com is in magento 1

Comment: Thanks for the suggesions. Good point with the order of test, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems out the ordinary there, just a website that hasn't been optimised very well.

It sounds like the images you downloaded have already been optimised by Google?

I can't add much more other than what Google already suggests, optimise images, utilise cache effectively, minify and concatenate static files, eliminate render blocking files where possible etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will definitely look into that.

But you don't ready the whole question, because I specifuy, that the google "optimized" images are not very optimal. 200x400px for a header image full screen desktop?

Comment: I've no idea about that, if there aren't any settings to change it I doubt you can do anything other than optimise them yourself or using a third party tool.

Comment: yeah, I'm using kraken.io alredy, but it does not take all images after all :/